# HTML images not showing in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css

I have embedded images onto my website using the HTML img tags. I thought there was not a problem as they looked fine, but they are not showing in Google Chrome.

By any chance is there a silly mistake in my HTML?

```
<a href="index.php">
    <img class="logo" src="images/navigation/logo.png" height="50">
    <img class="logotxt" src="images/navigation/logotxt.png" height="20">
</a>
```

Here is a link to the site for you to see for your self:

http://thetechreview.knightstone-it.co.uk/index.php

Comment: you are not serving images. do they even exist?

Comment: You were down voted because no one can see your file system making this question impossible to answer.

Furthermore they do not show on any browser meaning you are probably linking them wrong. Try `/images/navigation/logo.png` this is my arbitrary guess.

Comment: Neither in Opera or IE and images exists I believe otherwise chrome would log a not found error

Comment: They show fine in safari which is the wired part

Comment: Your image is not correct. Try resaving it in a proper format. It says png but it's not a png. (it looks like a psd to me)

Comment: ^ True. Chrome logs:
`Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type image/png: "http://thetechreview.knightstone-it.co.uk/images/navigation/logo.png".
Navigated to http://thetechreview.knightstone-it.co.uk/images/navigation/logo.png`

Comment: Can anyone confirm that it works in safari ?

Comment: yes I can confirm that

Comment: Just trued that thank you jasper, however it still doesn't work

Comment: Check the format by looking at the properties as @Ibu suggested. Is there another file in the same directory with the same name ? that might be interfering

Comment: Sadly thats not the problem,

Comment: Are you hosting this on an Apache server ?

Comment: For offline use I'm testing it in XAMPP, however i have uploaded it to a web server also

Comment: I can confirm that the logo at least is a photoshop document. Downloaded it, reamed it to logo.psd, opens in photoshop layers and all. Changing a file extension **does not change the file**!! Use photoshop's "Save for Web.." option instead.

Comment: No it is not a good thing. Browsers have no idea what to do with a photoshop document. Only gif, jpg (or jpeg), png or svg are supported widely by browsers.

Comment: Jon, I have just done as you suggested by saving all images for web in photoshop, thank you very much

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows a lack of fundamental understanding and it's become a long comment-fest rather than a Q&A

Answer (score 1):

Your path is wrong. There is no .png images on your path. So I tried guess correct extension. After few guess when I try psd, it's downloading psd image. Open your psd image with Photoshop or any other image editing program. Then save it as png (or jpg, gif etc) supporting type. Then use it.

```
http://thetechreview.knightstone-it.co.uk/images/navigation/logo.psd
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your .png images are wrong,checks that whether you can open them succeed on your computer or not